# Dropbox SDK 1.3.13 not support arm64

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I developed app using xcode6.2 , i have drop box sdk1.3.13  it is not support the arm64 so i removed this from valid architecture now my app work fine and my STANDARD ARCHITECTURE is armv7,arm64 and my VALID ARCHITECTURE is armv7 , armv7s. I submitted my app into appstore in my validation warning is

The archieve passed validation with several warnings

**iTunes store operation failed**

> > Missing 64-bit support. Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps
> >     uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built
> >     with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in
> >     your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of
> >     "Standard architectures" to build a single binary with both 32-bit and
> >     64-bit codes.

My Question is

1.If i will submit my app without clear this issue the appstore will accept or not?

2.Please clearly explain why the warning is occur , what mistake i did in my STANDARD ARCHITECTURE and VALID ARCHITECTURE

3.Why the Dropbox sdk 1.3.13 not supported the arm64 architecture?

Comment: The Dropbox iOS Core SDK version 1.3.13 does support arm64:

$ lipo -info dropbox-ios-sdk-1.3.13/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK
Architectures in the fat file: dropbox-ios-sdk-1.3.13/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK are: i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64

Where specifically do you see otherwise?