# Appstore Architecture warning

Tags: ios

I developed first version app in xcode 5 and the second version work with xcode 6 , in this version i have drop box sdk1.3.13 it is not support the arm64 so i removed this from valid architecture now my app work fine and my STANDARD ARCHITECTURE is armv7,arm64 and my VALID ARCHITECTURE is armv7 , armv7s. I submitted my app into appstore in my validation warning is

The archieve passed validation with several warnings

iTunes store operation failed

```
    Missing 64-bit support. Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of "Standard architectures" to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit codes.
```

My Question is

1.If i will submit my app without clear this issue the appstore will accept or not?

2.Please clearly explain why the warning is occur , what mistake i did in my STANDARD ARCHITECTURE and VALID ARCHITECTURE

3.Why the Dropbox sdk 1.3.13 not supported the arm64 architecture?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropbox SDK 1.3.13 not support arm64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765941/dropbox-sdk-1-3-13-not-support-arm64)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a) is what **Apple** says:

Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later.

To enable 64-bit in your project, Apple recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

So, Apple may reject your app if your app has this issue at the time of submission.